# Should I uninstall microsoft silverlight from production servers?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, .net

I'm trying to remove unwanted apps/features from our servers.
We have production servers running **ASP.Net MVC** websites, but we don't and never had any silverlight applications. The server has chrome and SSMS installed. 
So is it ok to uninstall Microsoft Silverlight from production servers (*since it's deprecated*) ?

The server is a **Windows Server 2012 R2** hosted on **AWS**.

[Screenshot of apps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKXBc.png)

Comment: Many of us would like to forget that Silverlight ever existed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Silverlight component on the server is a client component, not a server component. You can uninstall it.

Comment: As long as you don't use the classic Intune interface on that box ...